# Storing Session in mysql database using node js and express-mysql-session is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, express-session, session-storage

i am new in node js and i make a login system using session
and i am trying to store session data in database (i am using Xampp and phpmyadmin)
every thing is ok and req.session is available all over my application and session table created automatically in my database
but the session data didn't  stored in my database and session table is EMPTY
and i don't know why ? is there any thing missed ?

````
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const uuid = require('node-uuid');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const port = process.env.port || 3100;
app.listen(port , (err)=> {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }else {
        console.log('LISTENING');
    }
});
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
const connection = require('./db');
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
const sOpt = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'pharma-app',
}
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(sOpt);
app.use(session({
    strore: sessionStore,
    name: 'MyStrange-Cookie',
    secret: 'pharma-app',
    /*genid: function(req) {
        return uuid() // use UUIDs for session IDs
       },*/
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    }
  }))

app.get('/' , (req , res)=> {
    console.log(`Session . User ID ${req.session.userid}`);
    if (req.session.userid) {
        res.render('index' , {id: req.session.userid});
   }else {
        res.render('index' , {id: 'login to see the user data'})
   }
   console.log(req.session);
})
app.post('/signin' , (req , res)=> {
    req.session.userid = '456545654';
    console.log(req.sessionID);
    res.redirect('/');
})```
````

Comment: Is strore in 'strore: sessionStore,' a typo?

Comment: no it's correct and a table called 'session' automatically created in my db

Comment: @AndrewNaem "strore" is not correct

Comment: How i missed it >>> thanks alot dears